# IE10 will not load a CSS stylesheet of a certain name

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, stylesheet, internet-explorer-10

This is one of the strangest things I have ever seen. In the HTML file I have this link tag -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Classroom/engine/repository/PAGE_010100027/css/custom.PAGE_010100027.css">
```

The CSS is properly loaded and interpreted in all browsers save for IE10. I added the type="text/css" attribute in case the MIME type was somehow wrong -

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../Classroom/engine/repository/PAGE_010100027/css/custom.PAGE_010100027.css">
```

Still no dice.

So I copied the file and renamed it wtf.css (just for giggles) and changed the link tag to -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Classroom/engine/repository/PAGE_010100027/css/wtf.css">
```

It loads and interprets perfectly in IE10. :-/

We can name the file anything we want other than *custom.PAGE_010100027.css* and it will load fine in IE10. Even just changing one number. Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working? I'm stumped and I cannot find anything on the web concerning the naming of CSS files for IE10 and the other couple of hundred CSS files in this project using this naming convention load and interpret just fine. Thanks for any insight!

**UPDATE** I have confirmed that it is an odd caching issue of some sort. Whenever cache-busting techniques are applied the CSS file is loaded and interpreted correctly. Removing the cache-busting techniques causes IE10 to revert to a much older stylesheet. This only occurs on this one page (out of a couple of hundred).

Comment: Press F12 to open the debugger, watch the NETWORK page and see what sort of error the server is sending you.

Comment: It is not sending any errors. I forgot to mention that I have watched all of the loads carefully in each browser to note differences and to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Pop the same URL into the address of a new tab. See what you get.

Comment: We have tested across multiple machines, all with the same result. I am beginning to think that IE10 has cached this CSS file somehow since using a cache-buster to add a random date string to the end of the CSS file name alleviates the problem. Removing the cache buster returns to the problem. I would also think that a caching issue would affect ALL of the pages, not just this one. It is puzzling for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reading about related IE10 issues it could be related to the OS (Win8 versus Win7) and this setting: "Use TLS 1.0" (unchecking may solve the issue).